# background color with \mpcolor

Tags: beamer, luatex, metapost, luamplib, mptrees

I'm using following code and I would like to make the color of the background correspond to that of the beamer style. I tried the command `background:=\mpcolor{block body example.bg};` but it does not work.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,luamplib}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{}\centering\leavevmode
\begin{mplibcode}
input mptrees;
beginfig(1)
dirtree:=-90;
typeprob:=2;
% background:=\mpcolor{block body example.bg};
draw tree[1][1](1.25cm,5cm)("P","$\frac{1}{2}$","F","$\frac{1}{2}$");
draw tree[2][1](1.25cm,1.5cm)("R","$\frac{1}{5}$","B","$\frac{1}{5}$","N","$\frac{3}{5}$");
draw tree[2][2](1.25cm,1.5cm)("R","$\frac{1}{5}$","B","$\frac{1}{5}$","N","$\frac{3}{5}$");
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer-luamplib]

Comment: AFAIK, you have to fetch this color in the sources, convert it and pass it to metapost.

Comment: Yes, but for example the `background:=\mpcolor{red}` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, this is at least an example of how to include mptrees code in a latex document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `\mpcolor` command has been designed to be used after `withcolor` operator, it will not work in a simple assignment situation such as `background`. However, `xcolor` package provides a quite useful command, `\extractcolorspecs`, which we can use in the OP's example as follows:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\begin{document}
\mplibforcehmode
\begin{frame}
  \begin{exampleblock}{}\centering
    \extractcolorspecs{block body example.bg}\modelcmd\colorcmd
    \begin{mplibcode}
      input mptrees;
      beginfig(1)
      dirtree:=-90;
      typeprob:=2;
      background:=(\colorcmd);
      draw tree[1][1](1.25cm,5cm)("P","$\frac{1}{2}$","F","$\frac{1}{2}$");
      draw tree[2][1](1.25cm,1.5cm)("R","$\frac{1}{5}$","B","$\frac{1}{5}$","N","$\frac{3}{5}$");
      draw tree[2][2](1.25cm,1.5cm)("R","$\frac{1}{5}$","B","$\frac{1}{5}$","N","$\frac{3}{5}$");
      endfig;
    \end{mplibcode}
  \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

At line 8, `\modelcmd` gets to be `rgb`; `\colorcmd` gets to be `0.9,0.95,0.9` (xcolor manual 2.13). So, the latter can be made into a metapost color expression when put in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

With TikZ, we can put more nodes along the path. I think similar things can be done with Metapost, or it's better moving to TikZ ^^

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{}\centering\leavevmode
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2,xscale=1.5,font=\sffamily]
\path
(0,0)    coordinate (O)
(-2,-1)  node (F) {F} 
+(0,-1)  node (B1) {B}
+(-1,-1) node (N1) {N}
+(1,-1)  node (R1) {R}
(2,-1)   node (P) {P}
+(0,-1)  node (B2) {B}
+(-1,-1) node (N2) {N}
+(1,-1)  node (R2) {R};

\path 
(O)--(F) node[pos=.6] (OF) {$\frac{1}{2}$}
(O)--(P) node[pos=.6] (OP) {$\frac{1}{2}$}
(F.south)--(N1) node[pos=.6] (FN1) {$\frac{3}{5}$}
(F.south)--(B1) node[pos=.6] (FB1) {$\frac{1}{5}$}
(F.south)--(R1) node[pos=.6] (FR1) {$\frac{1}{5}$}
(P.south)--(N2) node[pos=.6] (PN2) {$\frac{3}{5}$}
(P.south)--(B2) node[pos=.6] (PB2) {$\frac{1}{5}$}
(P.south)--(R2) node[pos=.6] (PR2) {$\frac{1}{5}$}; 

\draw 
(O)--(OF) (OF)--(F) 
(O)--(OP) (OP)--(P)
(F.south)--(FB1) (FB1)--(B1) 
(F.south)--(FN1) (FN1)--(N1) 
(F.south)--(FR1) (FR1)--(R1)
(P.south)--(PB2) (PB2)--(B2)
(P.south)--(PN2) (PN2)--(N2)
(P.south)--(PR2) (PR2)--(R2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```